# Downgrade svn repository db format from 1.6 to 1.5

Tags: svn, migration

I do have an unusual situation, because I have to migrate an svn repostitory from svn-server 1.6 to svn-server 1.5. The issue is that the are no tools for downgrade available. Do anyone know some scripts or have the expirience with downgrading of svn repositories?

Cheers,

Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`svnsync`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt) to move the content from one repository to another.

Normally `svnsync` is intended for keeping a read-only mirror up to date, but I believe it will work fine for a one-time migration also. It also has the advantage of working purely as an SVN client, so you don't need administrative access on the server.

Comment: Having played with this myself now, you might want to clean up the svn:sync-* revprops once you're done: see `svn proplist --revprop -r 0` for the list

Answer (score 6):

Apart from Wim's suggestion svnsync the other option is a full dump / reload; use the Subversion 1.6 svnadmin to dump the repostitory out e.g.

```
svnadmin dump --incremental --deltas > dump_file
```

and then use 1.5 tools to load this back in to a clean repository

```
svnadmin create repository_15
svnadmin load repository_15 < dump_file
```

You will then have to copy over hooks from the old repository into the new repository and run `svnadmin pack` if you use that, etc.

Comment: Plus, svnadmin 1.7 and newer can create repositories in older formats (--pre-1.4-compatible/--pre-1.5-compatible/--pre-1.6-compatible options)

Answer (score 5):

Since subversion 1.8, it is possible to create a compatible repository without switching tooling.

## Extract

Extract the contents of the existing subversion repository using `svnadmin dump` or `svnrdump` for remote repositories:

```
svnadmin dump --incremental --deltas /path/to/local/repository > /tmp/repository.dump
```

## Recreate as v1.5 Compatible

Using `svnadmin` create a new 1.5 compatible repository and load in the previously dumped contents:

```
svnadmin create --compatible-version 1.5 /path/to/local/repository_15
svnadmin load /path/to/local/repository_15 < /tmp/repository.dump
```

Hooks and other repository settings will not be carried over and will need to be set up manually.

#### Subversion 1.7

Subversion 1.7 supports the ability to create compatible repositories using [the deprecated](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.html#svn.ref.svnadmin.sw.pre_1.4_compatible) `--pre-1.6-compatible` flag.

Comment: `--pre-X.X-compatible` options are deprecated. Use `--compatible-version X.X` with Subversion 1.8 and newer tools. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.html#svn.ref.svnadmin.sw.pre_1.4_compatible

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the answer to note the deprecation.