# Subversion on NAS

Tags: svn, debian, apache2, nas, debian-jessie

Our NAS got recent firmware upgrade and it broke subversion that we were using. Since repository was created using newer version of Tortoise SVN, we were unable to use the app listed in the store which is too older and not compatible with SVN files. So tried to get subversion 1.10.6, but facing issues to install. Could anyone please help to resolve the issue?

```
root@MyNAS:~/subversion-1.10.6# ./configure
configure: Configuring Subversion 1.10.6
configure: creating config.nice
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking if gcc accepts -std=c90... yes
checking if gcc accepts -w... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=unknown-warning-option... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking if g++ accepts -std=c++98... yes
checking if g++ accepts -w... yes
checking if g++ accepts -Werror=unknown-warning-option... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking build system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking host system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking target system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
configure: Apache Portable Runtime (APR) library configuration
checking for APR... yes
checking APR version... 1.5.1
configure: Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APRUTIL) library configuration
checking for APR-util... yes
checking APRUTIL version... 1.5.4
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
configure: serf library configuration via pkg-config
checking was serf enabled... no

An appropriate version of serf could not be found, so libsvn_ra_serf
will not be built.  If you want to build libsvn_ra_serf, please
install serf 1.3.4 or newer.

configure: looking for apr_memcache as part of apr-util
checking apr_memcache.h usability... yes
checking apr_memcache.h presence... yes
checking for apr_memcache.h... yes
checking for apr_memcache_create in -laprutil-1... yes
checking for Apache module support via DSO through APXS... no
==================================================================
WARNING: skipping the build of mod_dav_svn
         try using --with-apxs
==================================================================
configure: checking sqlite library
checking sqlite amalgamation... no
checking sqlite amalgamation... no
checking sqlite3.h usability... yes
checking sqlite3.h presence... yes
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking sqlite library version (via header)... okay
checking for sqlite3_close in -lsqlite3... yes
checking whether the compiler provides atomic builtins... yes
configure: configuring libtool now
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi file names to armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
configure: building both shared and static libraries
checking whether libtool needs -no-undefined... no
checking for trang... none
checking for doxygen... none
checking for Expat... yes
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for availability of Berkeley DB... no
checking whether to look for SASL... yes
configure: Looking in default locations
checking sasl/sasl.h usability... no
checking sasl/sasl.h presence... no
checking for sasl/sasl.h... no
checking for sasl/sasl.h... (cached) no
checking for availability of Cyrus SASL v2... no
checking for Mach-O dynamic module iteration functions... no
checking for Mac OS property list utilities... no
checking for Mac OS KeyChain Services... no
checking whether APR has support for DSOs... yes
checking whether to support GPG-Agent... yes
checking whether to look for old GNOME Keyring... no
checking whether to look for GNOME Keyring... yes
checking for GNOME Keyring... no
checking whether use Googlemock... no
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for library containing bindtextdomain... none required
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... yes
checking if we are using GNU gettext... yes
checking magic.h usability... no
checking magic.h presence... no
checking for magic.h... no
checking whether to look for KWallet... no
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working memcmp... yes
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking for symlink... yes
checking for readlink... yes
checking sys/utsname.h usability... yes
checking sys/utsname.h presence... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking for uname... yes
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking for tcgetattr... yes
checking for tcsetattr... yes
checking for -Wl,--no-undefined... yes
configure: C compiler flags: -g -O2   -pthread
configure:     user-defined:
configure:  maintainer-mode:
configure: C++ compiler flags: -g -O2
configure:       user-defined:
configure:    maintainer-mode:
configure: zlib library configuration via pkg-config
configure: zlib library configuration
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for inflate in -lz... yes
configure: lz4 configuration without pkg-config
checking for LZ4_compress_default in -llz4... no
configure: error: Subversion requires LZ4 >= r129, or use --with-lz4=internal
root@MyNAS:~/subversion-1.10.6#
```

So tried to use lz4 internal, then got different error.

```
root@MyNAS:~/subversion-1.10.6# ./configure --with-lz4=internal
.
.
.
configure: using internal lz4
configure: utf8proc configuration without pkg-config
checking for utf8proc_version in -lutf8proc... no
configure: error: Subversion requires UTF8PROC
root@MyNAS:~/subversion-1.10.6#
```

Since it was showing dependency on libapr1, libaprutil1 and libserf-dev, tried to install those, but it shows it is already newer version.

```
root@MyNAS:~/subversion-1.10.6# apt-get install libapr1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libapr1 is already the newest version (1.5.1-3).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim : Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u4) but 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

root@MyNAS:~# apt-get install libaprutil1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libaprutil1 is already the newest version (1.5.4-1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim : Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u4) but 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

root@MyNAS:~# apt-get install libserf-1-1 libserf-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libserf-1-1 is already the newest version (1.3.8-1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim : Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u4) but 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@MyNAS:~#
```

Comment: It may be easier to downgrade your copy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780751/downgrade-svn-repository-db-format-from-1-6-to-1-5  . You may want to check how to handle different client version (also here in SO)

Comment: Your question is full of vague statements ("broke subversion", "can't use some undisclosed software") but you're eventually asking how to compile Subversion from source in Debian. I think you should either explain the actual problem to get help about it or just ask how to compile.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, I am compiling Subversion 1.10.6. Tried to explain the problem I am facing with log, sorry to hear it was vague. While compiling Subversion, I got the errors as above.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you Giacomo